# Meteor SimpleSchema: prevent form submission using asynchronous custom validation

Tags: validation, meteor, simple-schema

I have implemented a custom validation function using the example referenced in the [SimpleSchema documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#asynchronous-custom-validation-on-the-client) for validating the uniqueness of a username. In the example, an asynchronous call is made and a custom validation message is displayed if the username is found to already exist.

There is a note, that indicates that if all of the form fields are valid, the form will be submitted, however user creation will fail due to the "unique: true" requirement specified in the schema. Here is the relevant portion of the code from the example docs:

```
username: {
 type: String,
 regEx: /^[a-z0-9A-Z_]{3,15}$/,
 unique: true,
 custom: function () {
   if (Meteor.isClient && this.isSet) {
     Meteor.call("accountsIsUsernameAvailable", this.value, function (error, result) {
    if (!result) {
          Meteor.users.simpleSchema().namedContext("createUserForm").addInvalidKeys([{name: "username", type: "notUnique"}]);
          }
    });
   }
  }
}
```

In my case, I have the code working where I am testing if an activation code is valid, I even get the interface to display the error, however since there is no other "schema" failure, the form submits, despite the invalid response...  do I need to manually prevent form submission (i.e. using jQuery), or is there something in SimpleSchema I should use instead?

```
activationCode: {
    type: String,
    label: "Activation Code",
    max: 200,
    min: 10,
    regEx: /^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+$/,
    custom: function() {
        if (Meteor.isClient && this.isSet) {
            Meteor.call("validateActivationCode", this.value, function(error, result) {

                if (result && !result.isValid) {
                    Clients.simpleSchema().namedContext("signupForm").addInvalidKeys([{
                        name: "activationCode",
                        type: "notValid"
                    }]);

                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Thank You